# why do I get an Error when I set ROS_WORKSPACE?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have installed Ros_groovy. And I  am creating my workspace with the tutorial:
"Installing and Configuring Your ROS Environment"

and everything goes okay, until I write:

john@john-G41D3C:~$ rosws set ~/groovy_workspace/sandbox

ERROR in config: Command requires a target workspace.

I try even with other name of my workspace, but i get the same error:

john@john-G41D3C:~$ rosws set ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox

ERROR in config: Command requires a target workspace.

What am i doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54073/why-do-i-get-an-error-when-i-set-ros_workspace-?/) by [Jey_316](https://answers.ros.org/users/3661/jey_316/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-02-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you create a new overlay first? `$rosws init ~/groovy_workspace /opt/ros/groovy`

---

Originally posted by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) with karma: 735 on 2013-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0